# Series inequality $\sum _{k=n}^{\infty } \frac{1}{k!}\leq \frac{2}{n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, factorial

Show that: $\displaystyle\sum _{k=n}^{\infty } \frac{1}{k!}\leq \frac{2}{n!}$

I am clueless here, I tried to multiply both sides with $n!$, but it doesn't make things better. I know that the left one converges against $e$ for $n=0$, but I better don't want to use its numerical value.

Comment: It's not true for $n=0$ :-)

Comment: Indeed.. But I got the solution now (thanks to Derek) :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint:
$$\frac{1}{(n+1)!} + \frac{1}{(n+2)!} + \cdots $$
$$= \frac{1}{n!} \left( \frac{1}{(n+1)} + \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} + \cdots \right) $$
$$ < \frac{1}{n!} \times \text{some geometric series}$$

Comment: Do you mean this? $\left( \frac{1}{(n+1)} + \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} + \cdots \right)<\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{(n+1)^k}=\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: @user3123 Yes, sorry for the late reply, though no doubt you've sorted the problem now.

Answer (score 5):

Estimate it using a geometric series.

Comment: Which side of the term?

Comment: The left one =)